# No Multiple Login on Same machine but same browser allowed

Tags: asp.net, authentication, declarative-authorization

I have a simple requirement of not allowing a user to log into multiple browsers at a time. Same browser is fine.

What is the simplest thing which can be done?

Technlogy : .net  4.0 and sql sever 2008 R2

Comment: What do you mean saying 'log into multiple browsers'?

Comment: Read the FAQ of SO. What have you tried? You should show your effort first. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: When i say Multiple browsers I mean to say that I am logged in IE and then i open FF and try to login, i should not be allowed. But if I open a new tab in IE then it is fine, as it is the same browser. If i go to a different machine and try to log-in , then i should not be allowed as i am already logged in on one machine in IE.

Comment: I have thought of using DB, storing the session in the DB and a flag of status 'Y' or 'N', so once i  login successfully i will update that flag with Y and enter the userid and session in DB so when a user is trying to login , i check for the status and come to know that he is already logged in. But problem is that if the user closes the browser by simlply clicking the close icon the session end event in globab.asax will not work untill session really expires.

Comment: Are you going to allow login using the same browser on different machines at the same time?

Comment: Hi Egor, No it should not be allowed.

Comment: Should login page be available from different browsers?

Comment: Yes it should be shown , for e.g in a machine: I login in IE and then i try to login in FF, then i should be allowed to login in FF, but when i again go to IE and try to access the same. i should not be allowed and should get a message that i am already logged in on a different browser or on the same machine ..

Comment: Is there 'Remember password' option? If yes - what should system do if I remembered password in IE. closed it. Then opened FF, logged in and opened IE again?

Comment: No it does not have 'Remember password'' option .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my advices below:

1. Store `LastActivityDate` for each user. If you are using asp.net `SqlMembershipProvider` - this field exists there, if you use another authentication mechanisms - probably you need to create it and update with each request of certain user.
2. Add an additional boolean field `LoggedIn` for each user. This field will be set to true when user does login. If you are using asp.net `SqlMembershipProvider` you can store its value in `Comment` field.
3. When user closes the browser send request to server to 'logout' user, which means set `LoggedIn` field to `false`. Use `window.onbeforeunload` javascript event for that.
4. On user login you should check `LoggedIn` field for the user, if it is false - you simply process the operation. If not - you should check `LastActivityDate` value, and if it older than a timeout you will define (lets say 3 minutes) process the operation. If not - reject it and show error message. This additinal check is required because we cannot guarantee that `window.onbeforeunload` is always executed.
5. The final step would be a javascript which consequentially calls a server action in timeout which updates `LastActivityDate`. This script should be defined on each page which is accessible for logged in user.

I hope the approach is clear.